# ios_type ^=0x1,what does this mean?

Tags: objective-c, c, ios

```
  - (void)methedName{
      if(){
        _type ^=0x1;
      }
    }
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question's title and your code do different things.

`0x1` means "1" interpreted as hexadecimal digits.  That happens to be the same as 1 in decimal.

So `_type =0x1` simply sets `_type` to 1.

`^` means the XOR (exclusive-or) operator.

`^=` means compute the XOR of the left-hand side with the right-hand side and assign the result to the left-hand side.  In other words, `ios_type ^= 0x1` is the same as `ios_type = ios_type ^ 0x1`.

So `ios_type ^= 0x1` toggles the 1 bit of `ios_type`.

Answer (score 4):

```
ios_type ^= 0x1
```

is equivalent to

```
ios_type = (ios_type ^ 0x1)
```

It sets `ios_type` to its original value XOR'ed with the constant value 1. That is, it toggles the 1 bit.

XOR (Exclusive-OR) Truth Table:

```
 INPUT    OUTPUT
 A   B    A XOR B 

 0   0      0
 0   1      1
 1   0      1
 1   1      0
```

Ref: [Exclusive OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)

Comment: Thanks,I see..any tip about XOR?

Answer (score 1):

It flips the Least Significant Bit of `ios_type`, so

```
10011010 ^ 00000001 ==> 10011011
10100111 ^ 00000001 ==> 10100110
```